# Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names

Tags: r, rbind

1. I am creating a vector having **5 age values** and named it as **boys_age**. Likewise created a vector named `girls_age`.

eg :

```
boys_age <- c(18,15,16,17,19)
girls_age<- c(16,14,18,17,15)
```

2. Then Append `rbind()` the two vectors to create **data.frame** such that I have two columns named `group` and `age`.
3. The values from  **boys_age** and **girls_age** should be in the column `age`. The `group` column should have the category values, **boys/girls**, to identify the source vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its actually the most primal thing to do in R:

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(boys_age = c(18,15,16,17,19), girls_age = c(16,14,18,17,15))
```

code:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), variable.name = "group", value.name = "age", measure.vars = c("boys_age", "girls_age"))[,2:1][,group:=sub("_.*$","",group)][]
```

result:

```
#    age group
# 1:  18  boys
# 2:  15  boys
# 3:  16  boys
# 4:  17  boys
# 5:  19  boys
# 6:  16 girls
# 7:  14 girls
# 8:  18 girls
# 9:  17 girls
#10:  15 girls
```

---

You seem to be keen on using `?rbind`: (not practical though)

```
rbind(
    cbind.data.frame(age = df1$boys_age,  group = "boys"),
    cbind.data.frame(age = df1$girls_age,  group = "girls")
    )

#   age group
#1   18  boys
#2   15  boys
#3   16  boys
#4   17  boys
#5   19  boys
#6   16 girls
#7   14 girls
#8   18 girls
#9   17 girls
#10  15 girls
```

- In the `?cbind` section I'm making use of the recycling functionality R provides. Read about it.
- Why am I using `cbind.data.frame`, otherwise cbind would create a matrix and therefore the age numerics would be converted to characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using `stack`

```
out <- stack(list(boys = boys_age, girls = girls_age))
out
#   values   ind
#1      18  boys
#2      15  boys
#3      16  boys
#4      17  boys
#5      19  boys
#6      16 girls
#7      14 girls
#8      18 girls
#9      17 girls
#10     15 girls
```

Now change names

```
names(out) <- c("age", "group")
out
#   age group
#1   18  boys
#2   15  boys
#3   16  boys
#4   17  boys
#5   19  boys
#6   16 girls
#7   14 girls
#8   18 girls
#9   17 girls
#10  15 girls
```

---

You could also do the same in one line, thanks to @Sotos

```
setNames(stack(list(boys = boys_age, girls = girls_age)), c('age', 'group'))
```

Comment: Nice 1. You can also do all in 1 line, i.e. `setNames(stack(list(boys = boys_age, girls = girls_age)), c('age', 'group'))`

Comment: Thank you, Markus, for your response. But the problem needs to be solved by using data.frame() and rbind() only. It's an exercise for data.frame and rbind function.

Comment: Not exactly, i am making some practice questions and got stuck with this.

Comment: @HimanshuGehlot Can you show us your attempt and where you got stuck then please?

Comment: @Sotos I am stuck how to group all age in one data.frame, likewise how to show subsequent boys_age/girls_age in front of respective age. Since I am trying using data.frame() function in rbind() and not getting suitable syntax for making groups.

Comment: @HimanshuGehlot When you do `data.frame(boys = boys_age, girls = girls_age)` you'd somehow need to reshape the output like @AndreElrico shows. `melt` is an option just like  `stack` is. But I don't see `rbind` here.

Comment: @HimanshuGehlot You can't do it directly with `rbind()` and `data.frame()` only. You could do something like `setNames(stack(data.frame(t(rbind(boys_age, girls_age)))), c('age', 'group'))` which includes them, but are not explicit

Comment: @Sotos What i have in my mind something like rbind(data.frame(AGE) , data.frame(GROUP)), i am not able to group the data in respective frame.

Comment: I suggest you read up on what `rbind` does using `?rbind` You can't do what you want with only `rbind` and `data.frame`

Comment: @AndreElrico your solution with rbind() is exactly what I was looking for, and yes I will read about"recycling functionality R". Thank you